# React componente renderizando duas vezes

Tags: react, react-hooks, react-dom

Pessoal estou com um problema em que meus componente são renderizados 2/3 vezes e estou desconfiado de uma implementação, porém não tenho certeza se é culpa dela.
A implementação é a seguinte, tenho um `LayoutContext` responsável por controlar as props que passo para meu layout da seguinte forma:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <LayoutProvider>
                <Provider {...store}>
                    <Routes></Routes>
                </Provider>
            </LayoutProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
}
```

}

Aqui é onde passo as props consumindo o meu `LayoutContext`:

```
  render() {
    const Layout = this.getLayout();
    // rendering the router with layout
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <LayoutContext.Consumer>
        {value => {
            return(
  
            <Layout 
                {...this.props}
                hideSearch={value.hideSearch}
                pageTitle={value.pageTitle}
                topBarModule={value.topBarModule}
                leftSideBarClass={value.leftSideBarClass}
                headChildren={value.headChildren}
            >
                <Switch>
                    {routes.map((route, index) => {
                        return (
                            !route.children && (
                                <route.route
                                    key={index}
                                    path={route.path}
                                    roles={route.roles}
                                    exact={route.exact}
                                    component={route.component}></route.route>
                            )
                        );
                    })}
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
                  )}}
                  </LayoutContext.Consumer>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
}
```

E depois para mudar o layout eu faço isso (Eu acho que o erro esta aqui), dentro do `ComponentDidMount` de cada componente que eu quero fazer a alteração de layout eu altero as props do meu `LayoutContext`:

```
    static contextType = LayoutContext;

componentDidMount() {
    console.log("passou aqui")
    const { financialBasics, setHeadChildren, setPageTitle } = this.context
    setPageTitle("Clientes e Fornecedores > Exibir Todos")
    setHeadChildren()
    financialBasics()
}
```

o `console.log` do `ComponentDidMount` é disparado duas vezes e se eu tiro o `LayoutContext` ele é disparado apenas uma vez, por isso desconfio que seja isso

#EDIT - 1

```
const Routes = (props) => {


const layoutContext = useContext(LayoutContext)

const layoutMemo = useMemo(() => {
    return layoutContext
}, layoutContext)

const propsMemo = useMemo(() => {
    return props
}, props)


// returns the layout
const getLayout = () => {

    if (layoutContext.isModule) return AuthLayout;

    let layoutCls = VerticalLayout;

    switch (props.layout.layoutType) {
        case layoutConstants.LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL:
            layoutCls = HorizontalLayout;
            break;
        case layoutConstants.LAYOUT_DETACHED:
            layoutCls = DetachedLayout;
            break;
        default:
            layoutCls = VerticalLayout;
            break;
    }
    return layoutCls;
};



const Layout = getLayout();

return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout
            {...propsMemo}
            {...layoutMemo}
        >
            <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, index) => {
                    return (
                        !route.children && (
                            <route.route
                                key={index}
                                path={route.path}
                                roles={route.roles}
                                exact={route.exact}
                                component={route.component}></route.route>
                        )
                    );
                })}
            </Switch>
        </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    layout: state.Layout,
    user: state.Auth.user,
   };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Routes)
```

Comment: A cada mudança de propriedades ou `props`. a arvore é atualizada. Você tem razão é isso que acontece mesmo. Como os elementos compartilham da mesma propriedades os outros que tem precisam saber dessa alteração se não ficam desatualizados. Isso não é problema basicamente falando é o funcionamento mesmo. Estude `memo` que pode te ajudar a melhorar isso

Comment: Também da uma olhada no seu index.js. React no StrictMode, renderiza 2 vezes para verificar possiveis erros, depois após o build não acontece isso.

Comment: @novic obrigado, então a implementação não esta errada, mas poderia ser melhorada com o memo? Esse memo impediria essa dupla renderização?

Comment: @Kakiz como sei se estou usando o StrictMode?

Comment: sim pode ... tem que saber utilizar `memo` https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo e https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: @GuilhermePrado no seu arquivo index.js, veja se seu ```<App/>``` esta envolvido por ```<React.StrictMode>```

Comment: @novic estudei sobre o memo e realmente ele parece muito vantajoso obrigado!
Mesmo ainda não resolvendo meu problema foi legal ver como ele funciona, faz sentido a refatoração que fiz usando memo? Ela esta no "#EDIT 1" do meu post.
Fiquei em duvida se deveria usar o memo nesta etapa ou dentro do LayoutContext.
Obrigado!

Comment: Sinceramente eu não tenho como testar